# What are best VIM plugins to configure efficiency?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

There are a lot of options with VIM that can be configured, and many of the are related to memory management and speed up, or some related to file opening and utf8 support. What plugins can I install to manage all of these in one place for me?

Answer (score 6):

Tim Pope's [sensible.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4391) offers a basic set of configuration options as a starting point, mostly because many Vim defaults aren't optimal for most users today. Apart from that, you have to (or don't, if you are fine with the defaults) tweak the Vim options yourself, because every workflow is unique, and Vim is a particularly configurable editor, and unbiased in its approach.

Vim "distributions" like *spf-13* and *Janus* lure you with a quick install and out of the box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.

So, start with a basic configuration, and whenever you feel something's not optimal for you, go on a journey, investigate available options in the excellent and comprehensive `:help`, search other's .vimrc's on the Internet, and tweak your config. Rinse and repeat regularly.

Comment: And I'm the one who managed to *not* talk about distributions in my answer! ;-)

Comment: Currently I have some basic configurations for myself, but it has a lot of problems and I'm looking for something better. Changing it would be a good idea, as it has been always this way with VIM ;)

Comment: Then fix those problems. One by one. Changing your whole config just to avoid fixing its problems is, well… rather cowardly. Ask a question or two here, explaining clearly what works, what doesn't and what you expect along with the content of your `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing.

*You* are supposed to manage Vim's options by adding/editing them manually in your `~/.vimrc`.

The `:options` command lets you set all of Vim's options in one place but your changes won't stick between sessions.

The only sane way to have your settings persist is to add them to your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: May be I asked with bad words, I need a set of commands for `~/.vimrc`, I thought they might be packed in a plugin.

Comment: No. *You* must take care of *your* settings *yourself* according to *your* workflow, *your* needs and *your* taste. There are possibly hundreds of "minimal .vimrc" or "definitive plugin distributions" floating around the internet but all these things are just compilations of settings that work for one blogger and **may or may not work for you**. If you find something that you don't like in Vim, find how to change it in `:help` and do that in your `~/.vimrc`. This file will grow/shrink overtime and that's how it's supposed to be.

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy Vim comes with an example vimrc file, which has reasonable defaults. I suggest you start with that. See the instructions at [`:h not-compatible`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_01.html#not-compatible).